# Is it possible and how create a trigger with Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, database-trigger

Is it possible to create a SQL trigger with Entity Framework Core.

Maybe by using instruction in

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder dbModelBuilder)
{
}
```

Or simply by executing SQL statements in Migration scripts

```
public override void Up()
{
}
```

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Ah ok. Trigger is not standard?

Comment: In theory: yes - pretty much every serious RDBMS has triggers. But the exact syntax and their capabilities vary quite a bit from product to product ....

Comment: No fluent API so far, so option (2) - `migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE TRIGGER …")` etc.

Comment: And it is not possible to extend the fluent API to create an action that will fill the Up() method? I guess no because I don't know then how fluent API can compare with snapshot. I'm very disappointed by this Core version of EF because I was really expecting a improvement of how defining his model and have more control on DB.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(@"create trigger .....");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql(@"drop trigger <triggerName>");
    }
```

Comment: this fails when generating SQL because it tries to create a trigger from within a strored procedure

Comment: @Chazt3n, can you provide the example you have tried?

Comment: thank you for reminding me about this. This WON'T fail unless you specify --idempotent when generating SQL. I did not know this had been changed in our CI Pipeline

Answer (score 11):

[Laraue.EfCoreTriggers](https://github.com/win7user10/Laraue.EfCoreTriggers) package for creating SQL triggers through fluent syntax which allows to execute insert, update, upsert, delete, insert if not exists statements after trigger has worked like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>()
    .AfterInsert(trigger => trigger
        .Action(triggerAction => triggerAction
            .Upsert(transaction => new { transaction.UserId },
                insertedTransaction => new UserBalance { UserId = transaction.UserId, Balance = insertedTransaction.Sum },
                (insertedTransaction, oldBalance) => new UserBalance { Balance = oldBalance.Balance + insertedTransaction.Sum })));
```

This code will be translated into sql and applied to migrations using

```
migrationBuilder.Sql()
```

Comment: thanks for this library, unfortunately when I try to write  ```modelBuilder.Entity<AvailabilitySettings>().AfterInsert(trigger => trigger
            .Action(ta =>
                ta.Update<AvailabilitySettings>(
                    (insertedEntity, searchedEntity) => insertedEntity.Id == searchedEntity.Id, 
                    (insertedEntity, foundEntity) => (new AvailabilitySettings(foundEntity) { Revision = foundEntity.Id }))
             ));```
nothing is generated in Up method when executing `dotnet ef migrations add AMigration`

Comment: Have you used extension .UseTriggers() while configuring your DbContext?

Comment: Yes I did. Maybe just a thing to tell. My dbcontext is in a separate library. And I use a connection string from inside the class hard coded for migrations commands

Comment: Could you provide source code repository which reproduce the problem?